Vespa visit 504 Gateway timeouts
I need to fetch couple million worth of records from Vespa. I am utilising vespa visit CLI command and --slice to have the data in manageable chunks. I have tried various slice sizes and but still receive the 504 error. Perhaps some one has also encountered this issue? All help is appreciated.

the 504 indicates poor health of the vespa cluster. The description does not say whether this is a one-node or multi-node cluster - a common problem for many is a cluster too low on memory resources, so make sure the processes can run without failing. Checking vespa.log helps.
It helps knowing how you run the Vespa cluster, too (self-hosted or in Vespa cloud).
It also does not say if you can get some data, then a 504 / if all are 504.
https://vespa.ai/developer/ has some resources to help you, in particular the Community Slack, where it is easy to post your configuration and log/error messages + the the information missing above.
